# How to make div refresh fade in and out instead of flicker with updated content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I use jquery to fade in and out a div with updated content everytime the div is refreshed? Ex: Updating stock quotes every second so refresh with fade in and out number every time updated 3 seconds.

Comment: Call `.fadeOut()` with a complete callback (the jQuery doco for `.fadeOut()` has an example of this). In the callback set the new content and then call `.fadeIn()`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please review [ask] -- providing your code, context, and a specific, reproducible problem will go a long way in engaging the community and getting good guidance.

Comment: Alright sounds good. However when I do this it only refresh one part of a class instead all the content within the class. Any help there? For instance fadeOut and fadeIn certain elements of a class with updated content every refresh